# Zoho Crm API2 Created_By & Modifed_BY not updated by request

Tags: php, crm, zoho

I try to add record to lead, and its work fine, but inserted record not updated a created_by and modified_by name.

```
$bulkStatus = ZohoCrm::addLeadsRecord([
                'Email' => $model->email,
                'First_Name' => $model->full_name,
                'Description' => $model->message,
                'Phone' => $model->phone,
                'Country' => $model->country,
                'Last_Name' => $model->full_name,
                'Created_By' => ["name" => "Hadi", "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
                'Modified_By' => ["name" => "Hadi", "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
                '$gclid' => isset($_POST['zc_gad']) ? $_POST['zc_gad'] : 'Undefined!',
                "Owner" => [
                        "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "name" => "Hadi"
],
"Lookup" => [
        "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "name" => "Hadi"
],
```

Note: I try this too but not work too

```
'Created_By' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
'Modified_By' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a right attempt.created_by and modified_by **can't be updated**.